_block.LZ4BlockError: Decompression failed: corrupt input or insufficient space in destination buffer. Error code: 10978
Can you please help me with this? Environment: RHEL8 with Python 3.11
I am using msgpack1.0.8 and lz4 4.1.0 and I have been getting this error frequently.
_block.LZ4BlockError: Decompression failed: corrupt input or insufficient space in destination buffer. Error code: 2165
The Error code varies - it wont be same every time it prints.
Any help in solving the problem of Decompression failed? Thanks!
Tried in local RHEL8 with Python 3.11. Can someone help me resolve this? Thanks!
_block.LZ4BlockError: Decompression failed: corrupt input or insufficient space in destination buffer. Error code: 2165
